# Implications of setting up an automated monitoring tool like pingdom against the IIS?

Tags: iis, monitoring

Are there any concerns I should do if I want to set up a pingdom like monitoring tool against a website hosted on IIS? I know that the IIS like to shut down and recycle app pools when it's been idle for some time, but with a monitoring service that is constantly pinging it, it will never (?) be able to do so..

Can I go ahead anyway?

Comment: Yes, you can go ahead. You will do no harm.

Answer (score 0):

Its fine - if you want your app pool to recycle (to free up memory for example) you can set up other triggers (e.g. time / memory threshold) to recycle it.

In many cases it is preferable not to have your app pool recycle for an idle time-out. You may have in memory caches that need to be rebuilt and which will cause the next round of requests to the app pool to be pretty slow. Pinging it with pingdom will eliminate this issue.